# What does "was had tonight" mean?

Tags: past-tense, passive-voice

A friend of mine from USA posted this:

> "So much fun was had tonight with this fantastic group!"

I am not a native speaker so, I do not understand "was had tonight". I have never heard this expression before. What is this in terms of grammar?

Comment: It is a time-honored custom in the US, after a party or some fun event, for a person to report on it afterwards, in a small town newspaper, for example, or in a company newsletter, using a passive construction similar to "A good time *was had* by all". https://books.google.com/books?id=z2U1q1iVHtAC&pg=PA110&dq=%22a+good+time+was+had%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=eXFYVYqTBOXHsQTpxoCgDQ&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22a%20good%20time%20was%20had%22&f=false

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a%20good%20time%20was%20had%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1800,cd_max:1923&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Have fun*** is an expression meaning something like "enjoy oneself".

> We **had so much fun** tonight!

This sentence means something like "We enjoyed ourselves very much tonight".

Now let's turn our active clause into a passive clause:

> **So much fun was had** by us tonight!

Now that our example is in the passive, we can remove the ***by***-phrase:

> **So much fun was had** tonight!

This sentence means something very similar to our first example, except that it no longer specifies who had fun.  It could be "by us" or "by all", for example.

> **So much fun was had** tonight *with this fantastic group*!

This makes it sound like lots of people enjoyed themselves very much, quite possibly everyone involved.

Answer (score 5):

This is a passive sentence.  The true subject of the idea being expressed is treated as an object.  Sometimes this is done when it is difficult to define exactly who the subject is. Other times it is just awkward and extra-wordy.

This sentence could be re-written: *We had so much fun with this fantastic group* or *They had so much fun with this fantastic group*.

Answer (score -2):

I believe the sentence is not grammatically correct.

To me this is wordplay. In a novel (or *formal* accounting of some episode) one might say "Much food was consumed that night."

Hope this helps.

Comment: The sentence is neither ungrammatical nor an instance of wordplay; there is nothing inherently humorous in the way that words are being used here. As MJ6 points out in their answer, it is merely a sentence where the action is described in the passive voice: "We have had so much fun..." is thus transformed into "So much fun was had....".